# Amazon Simple Notification Service AWSSDK C# - S.O.S

Tags: c#, sdk, amazon-web-services

I am trying to publish with Amazon's AWSSDK for C# and the Simple Notification Service.

There are no samples that come with the SDK and there are no samples anywhere on the web I could find after 2 hours of Googling. I came up with this but it is throwing an exception that yields no more information than the single string, "TopicARN" - no inner exception - nuffin!
If anyone has successfully sent a message with `SNS` via C# using the **AWSSDK** I would love to see even the most rudimentary working example. I am using the latest SDK 1.5x

Here's the code:

```
string resourceName = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:StackOverFlowStub";
AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient snsclient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(accesskey,secretkey);
AddPermissionRequest permissionRequest = new AddPermissionRequest()
                .WithActionNames("Publish")
                .WithActionNames(accesskey)
                .WithActionNames("PrincipleAllowControl")
                .WithActionNames(resourceName);
snsclient.AddPermission(permissionRequest);

PublishRequest pr = new PublishRequest();
pr.WithMessage("Test Msg");
pr.WithTopicArn(resourceName);
pr.WithSubject("Test Subject");
snsclient.Publish(pr);
```

Comment: Here is the link for codes : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html

Comment: That's garbage, the link doesn't have any code of how to publish a notification in SNS.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a sample that creates a topic, sets a topic display name, subscribes an email address to the topic, sends a message and deletes the topic. Note that there are two spots where you should wait/check your email before continuing. `Client` is the client instance, `topicName` is an arbitrary topic name.

```
// Create topic
string topicArn = client.CreateTopic(new CreateTopicRequest
{
    Name = topicName
}).CreateTopicResult.TopicArn;

// Set display name to a friendly value
client.SetTopicAttributes(new SetTopicAttributesRequest
{
    TopicArn = topicArn,
    AttributeName = "DisplayName",
    AttributeValue = "StackOverflow Sample Notifications"
});

// Subscribe an endpoint - in this case, an email address
client.Subscribe(new SubscribeRequest
{
    TopicArn = topicArn,
    Protocol = "email",
    Endpoint = "sample@example.com"
});

// When using email, recipient must confirm subscription
Console.WriteLine("Please check your email and press enter when you are subscribed...");
Console.ReadLine();

// Publish message
client.Publish(new PublishRequest
{
    Subject = "Test",
    Message = "Testing testing 1 2 3",
    TopicArn = topicArn
});

// Verify email receieved
Console.WriteLine("Please check your email and press enter when you receive the message...");
Console.ReadLine();

// Delete topic
client.DeleteTopic(new DeleteTopicRequest
{
    TopicArn = topicArn
});
```

Comment: Osyan. This works and is EXCELLENT. Would you mind commenting how you arrived at this code considering the lack of samples on the net including the AWS Site?

Comment: There are various [documentation resources on the official AWS site](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/), such as the [Getting Started with Amazon SNS Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/Welcome.html). You can also find helpful information and ask questions on the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa).   
But, sometimes it just helps to be on the .NET SDK team. :)

Comment: Perfect.  This has everything that I need.  Thanks.

Comment: @PavelSafronov are there any docs on how to set up the client object here? Lola how did you know to do the add permissions?

Comment: The [AWS SDK for .NET user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/welcome.html) a good place to check out when you're starting out with the SDK. That being said, the simplest way to construct a client object is like this: `var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);`

Comment: is there an example of how to create a C# application that is a SNS client directly? (rather than subscribe to an email as here)