# Timeout error for AWS SNSClient Publish request

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Here is the piece of code :

```
                        //Publishing the topic
                        snsClient.Publish(new PublishRequest
                        {
                            Subject = Constants.SNSTopicMessage,
                            Message = snsMessageObj.ToString(),
                            TopicArn = Settings.TopicArn
                        });
```

I am getting the below error :

> The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected
>   to be kept alive was closed by the server.

And here is the screenshot of detailed error:
[image]

But not able to get an idea how to solve this. Any hint or link will helpful.

Comment: Maybe too obvious but is snsClient valid (i.e. properly connected, existing credentials, region...)?

Comment: Yes @Gonfva. They are valid. I am able to do the operations. But I am getting the error infrequently. But still it need to be addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the exact same issue happen to us. We got this error about 40 times a day, which was less than 0.1% of the successful push notifications we sent out.

Our solution? Update the AWSSDK NuGet package from 1.5.30.1 to 2.3.52.0 (the latest v2 release for ease-of-upgrade). As soon as we updated, the errors stopped happening. I looked through lots of release notes and couldn't find anything specifically mentioning this issue. We have no idea why the update worked, but it did.

I hope this helps you and anyone else fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will update the version and will let you know the results.

Comment: Yes. U r right. Up gradation does fix the thing. Now, I am not getting any of those timeouts. Thx a ton.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur when one or more of the following conditions are true:

•   A network outage occurs.

•   A proxy server blocks the HTTP request.

•   A Domain Name System (DNS) problem occurs.

•   A network authentication problem occurs.

[[https://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/03/01/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server/][1](http://[https://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/03/01/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server/][1])](http://[https://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/03/01/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server/][1])

Comment: The problem only occurs rarely . Like in 6000 sns msgs only 10-15 times max. So, I am not sure about your suggestions to the problems.

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida, Check your Amazon sns initialization code. Amazon will automatically discontinue it's connection after few time. So, I think you should paste all code. so people can easily understand, from which sentence you are getting this kind of problem.

Comment: @BhavikPatel , here is the initialization code:
 snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(Settings.AccessKey, Settings.SecretKey, regionEndPoint);

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida are those 600 sns msgs being sent at once?

Comment: Not at once but a program is sending one after another?

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida Could it be that you are running out of socket connections on your server?

Comment: Not always. But I do sometimes have the below error among the connection closed error. Hope you will find a clue for here :

http://tinypic.com/r/2movzt5/8

Comment: I would look into port exhaustion described in this article, http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- make sure your payloads size should not exceed more than 256 kb
- make sure you had configured timeout property of the PutObjectRequest

Take a look sample aws sns request code (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13016803/2318852)

```
// Create topic
string topicArn = client.CreateTopic(new CreateTopicRequest
{
    Name = topicName
}).CreateTopicResult.TopicArn;

// Set display name to a friendly value
client.SetTopicAttributes(new SetTopicAttributesRequest
{
    TopicArn = topicArn,
    AttributeName = "DisplayName",
    AttributeValue = "StackOverflow Sample Notifications"
});

// Subscribe an endpoint - in this case, an email address
client.Subscribe(new SubscribeRequest
{
    TopicArn = topicArn,
    Protocol = "email",
    Endpoint = "sample@example.com"
});

// When using email, recipient must confirm subscription
Console.WriteLine("Please check your email and press enter when you are subscribed...");
Console.ReadLine();

// Publish message
client.Publish(new PublishRequest
{
    Subject = "Test",
    Message = "Testing testing 1 2 3",
    TopicArn = topicArn
});

// Verify email receieved
Console.WriteLine("Please check your email and press enter when you receive the message...");
Console.ReadLine();

// Delete topic
client.DeleteTopic(new DeleteTopicRequest
{
    TopicArn = topicArn
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to check payload size. Like if else or try catch block piece of code.

Comment: I have checked the payloads . In my case it's max 3kb-4kb. The limit is 256kb. So I don't think payload is an issue here.@bhavik